How can I enable WiFi for my laptop? I go to the network settings and only the proxy and Vpn appears,
When I connect via cable, the wired configuration option is enabled. Does anyone know how I can enable the WiFi settings?
I want to be able to connect to the network via wifi, but no option appears, please help me.

Sounds like your wifi device isn't being detected.  Do you see it in ip addr ?  Is it listed in lspci  ?   If it is not listed in the former but is listed in the latter, you don't have a device driver for it loaded that recognizes it.

Your question is not answerable. You have not told us anything about your computer and the kind of OS it is running and its version. For example is it running Windows 3.1 or NT? Edit your question and add all the information we ask for inside your question. Copy and paste the output of the commands ip addr and lspcidirectly in your question. Then format the pasted output as code using the {_} above the edit window.

This question is similar to: My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
